# Using a function to add a column in R data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function in R which lumps species columns together within a data.frame.

(To elaborate a bit on what I'm doing...I have a data frame with multiple plant species for multiple sites and years. Some of the species were misidentified, so I'd like to group to a more general level (e.g. spp a and spp b were mixed up throughout the years; so I'd like to create a new column called spp.ab in which the data for spp a and b are lumped together)).

Example:

```
spp.a spp.b
  1     0
  2     3
  0     4
  3     2
  4     5
```

I'd like to eventually end up with a single column that displays the maximum from value from the two species:

```
spp.ab
  1
  3
  4
  3
  5
```

I've started writing a function which does this; however, I'm having troubling adding the new column to my data set and dropping the old ones. Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
lump <- function(db, spp.list, new.spp) { #input spp.list as c('spp.a', 'spp.b', ...)
  mini.db <- subset(db, select=spp.list);
  newcol <- as.vector(apply(mini.db, 1, max, na.rm=T));
  db$new.spp <- newcol
  db <- db[,names(db) %in% spp.list]
  return(db)
}
```

When I call the function as such

```
test <- lump(db, c('spp.a', 'spp.b'), spp.ab)
test
```

all that pops up is the mini.db. Am I missing something with return()?

For reference, db is the database, spp.list is the species I want to lump together, and new.spp is what I would like the new column named.

Thanks for any help,
Paul

Answer (score 3):

I've figured it out...stupid mistake, of course. Here is the code that works:

```
lump <- function(db, spp.list, new.spp) { #input spp.list as a c('spp.a', 'spp.b', ...), and new.spp must be in quotes (e.g. 'new.spp')
    mini.db <- subset(db, select=spp.list);
    newcol <- as.vector(apply(mini.db, 1, max, na.rm=T));
    newcol[newcol==-Inf] <- NA;
    db[new.spp] <- newcol;
    db <- db[, !names(db) %in% spp.list];
    return(as.data.frame(db));
 }
```

The key is in the `db[new.spp] <- newcol;` line. Apparently using this works, but using `db$new.spp <- newcol` does not. I also then added a `!` to the line `db <- db[,!names(db) %in% spp.list]`. This was my biggest mistake.

Comment: So `new.spp` is the name of the new column?

Comment: Correct, and you can call it whatever you like by placing the name in quotes as an argument to the function. For example, if you want to call it el.conquistador you would input lump(db, c('spp.a', 'spp.b'), 'el.conquistador')

Answer (score 2):

While it seems like you've found your answer, I would suggest, instead, the `pmax` function:

```
> with(db, pmax(spp.a, spp.b))
[1] 1 3 4 3 5
```

You can use this with `within` or `transform` to mimic your function:

```
out <- within(db, spp.ab <- pmax(spp.a, spp.b))
out
#   spp.a spp.b spp.ab
# 1     1     0      1
# 2     2     3      3
# 3     0     4      4
# 4     3     2      3
# 5     4     5      5
```